The question about "trumping" in Lewis's "causation as influence
In Lewis's "Causation as Influence," in section 1.4 titled "Trumping," Lewis describes a scenario as a case where a causal chain can be said to preempt a potential causal chain under the following two conditions.

there is a completed causal chain running from the preempting cause all the way to the effect
something cuts short the potential alternative causal chain that would, in the absence of the preempting cause, have run from the preempted alternative to the effect

And Lewis illustrates this with the example of a Major's command blocking a sergeant's command. He then points out the epistemic possibility that "the sergeant's command forms an obstacle cutting the signal of the sergeant's command." In this case, Lewis argues that the example of the Major and sergeant can also be seen as a case of preemption without cutting
"it is epistemically possible, and hence it is possible simpliciter, that this is a case of preemption without cutting(p. 81)"
The question that arises here is whether the epistemic situation Lewis posits, namely, that the Major's command blocking the signal from the Sergeant seems to block the causal chain from the sergeant's command as the cause to the soldiers advancing as the effect.
In line with Lewis's views, when considering why this case might be a case of preemption without cutting, it seems to be due to the following reasons:
If the Major's command creates an obstacle that interferes with the sergeant's command, it becomes the causal event leading to the effect as cutting sergeant's command. Consequently, no causal chain exists between the sergeant's command and the soldiers advancing. Thus, there would be no potential chain to block, making it a case of preemption without cutting possible.
However, in response to this, one could argue that if the Major's command is absent, there would be no obstacle, and therefore, the sergeant's command would have been executed properly. In that case, wouldn't the Major's command fit the definition of cutting, making it a contradictory case to Lewis's notion of preemption without cutting?
However, this argument presupposes that there exists a potential causal chain from the sergeant's command to the soldiers' advancement. Therefore, if Lewis's claim posits that the Major's command, when considering the epistemic conditions of creating an obstacle, results in preemption without blocking, then claiming that the 'original example + epistemic conditions' does not meet the conditions of cutting is essentially the same argument.
With the exception that the sergeant's command is not yet justified as the causal event of a potential causal chain in my argument, the rest seems to meet the conditions of cutting. This is because Condition 1, which states that a complete chain exists between the Major's command and the soldiers' advancement, is already satisfied.
Therefore, considering the epistemic situation, for the Major-sergeant example to be a case of preemption without cutting according to Lewis's claim, Condition 2 should not be satisfied. That is, considering the epistemic conditions, it should be shown that the causal chain from sergeant's command to effect can also be viewed as not a potential causal chain.
This seems to counter the question I posed earlier: "If the Major's command is absent, there would be no obstacle, and therefore, the sergeant's command would have been executed properly. In that case, is there the potential causal chain from sergeant's command to effect as advancing? Thus, doesn't the sergeant's command fit the definition of cutting?" I'm struggling to understand why, when considering the epistemic situation, it can be viewed as preemption without cutting.
